# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints error whats causing this?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift5

[image]ca someone help me with this

```
    import UIKit
    import Firebase

class aboutmeViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
var refrelation : DatabaseReference!


@IBOutlet weak var me: UITableView!


var relationList = [aboutmeModel] ()
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return relationList.count
}
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
    let relation: aboutmeModel
    relation = relationList[indexPath.row]
    cell.fname.text = relation.firstname
    cell.lname.text = relation.lastname
    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    refrelation.observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot)in
        if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
            self.relationList.removeAll()

            for relations in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]{
                let relationObject = relations.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let firstname = relationObject? ["firstName"]
                let lastname = relationObject? ["lastname"]
                let pob = relationObject?["dob"]
                let age = relationObject?["relation"]
                let id = relationObject?["id"]

               let relation = aboutmeModel (id: id as!
                                      String?, firstname:  firstname  
as! String?, lastname: lastname as! String?, relation: age as! String?, 
dob: pob as! String?)
                                  self.relationList.append(relation)
            }
            self.me.reloadData()


        }
    })
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


/*
```

this is my subclass for the table view

```
   import UIKit

  class ViewControllerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var fname: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var age: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var placeofbirth: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lname: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

what i want my app to do is to fetch the data from the database and display it in the aboutmeviewcontroller, however the app wont even run, i tried following a tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ge56yTgnjKs&t=263s thats the link, however I keep on getting an error, can someone please help!

this is the error im getting.

"Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want."

Comment: Did you give `delegate and datasource` to the tableview? Also, have you added the `identifier` for cell?

Comment: Click right on the Storyboard file, Open as Source Code. Look for `gdF-Z7-MpJ` inside it, copy/paste occurrences here (surrounding occurrences), there seems to an issue. Also, `addPeeps`, where is it? Or where WAS it (did you removed it?) You seem to have multiple issues.

Comment: yes i've added the delegate and datasource to the tableview

Comment: The crash in the screenshot has nothing to do with *Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints*. The crash occurs because `refrelation` is declared but not set.

Comment: how do i set it, its already set in another viewcontroller

Comment: Any view controller has its own scope (`{}`) which is invisible for other controllers unless you have a reference provided by a segue or instantiation.

Comment: there is a segue between the two view controllers. so why isnt it working?

Comment: You have to set `refrelation` explicitly in `prepare(for segue`

Comment: override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "refrelation" {
            let refrelation = segue.destination as! addViewController
            
        }
    } .  is this ok? because its still not workig